# Register and pay online

Tags: 7, users, commerce

I would like our website can register right.
Such registration is: After the user fields to fill out the registration page to enter paid. If payment was successful record in the user database is placed.

These payments are: When users get paid by the banks a record is submitted to my site.
This must be paid to confirm a few fields of this record to send back to the bank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to read this: http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/03/event-registration-ubercart

It's a walk through of setting up an "event registration" system in Drupal - however, that is really just a web site that:

```
1) presents introduction information about a product or service
2) After a customer clicks "Add to cart", presents the customer with a form to complete of
   needed info for that product/service
3) if the customer's credit/debit transaction is successful, the customer's purchase is 
   identified as "valid" and your web site does whatever you offered in the way of 
   product/service for your customer.
```

This is achieved with Ubercart, Ubercart's Conditional Actions, and some minor tweaking fully explained in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ubercart Event Registration](http://drupal.org/project/uc_event_registration). This creates an Ubercart product class which is also a webform. You can then create one of these for each type of subscription. Ubercart already has functionality for creating the user on purchase. You would just want to add some logic to assign a certain role to the user when payment's verified (as otherwise you could cancel the payment but the user account will still have been created).